# automake for creating a lib and program using it

Tags: makefile, automake

I'm trying to develop a program that uses another internal library done in the same project.

I want to link both. The lib is stored and succesfully compiled under ./lib/mylib and a mylib.a is created. The issue is that I need to include ./lib/mylib directory in the INCLUDE search and also link the program against the library.

Are there any automatically defined variables or do I have to do it by my own like in the Makefile.am below?

```
SUBDIRS = lib .

# set the include path found by configure
INCLUDES = $(all_includes) -Ilib/mylib

bin_PROGRAMS = myprogram

myprogram_SOURCES = main.c 
myprogram_CPPFLAGS =  $(libmylib_CFLAGS) $(AM_CFLAGS) $(CFLAGS)
nfc_network_config_LDADD =$(LIB_MYLIB)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `Makefile` could look something like this.

```
SUBDIRS = lib .
bin_PROGRAMS = myprogram
myprogram_SOURCES = main.c
myprogram_CPPFLAGS = -Ilib/mylib $(AM_CPPFLAGS) 
myprogram_LDADD = lib/mylib/mylib.a
```

Note that `*_CPPFLAGS` should usually not be mixed with  `*_CFLAGS`, and that the `$(CFLAGS)` and `$(CPPFLAGS)` variables are always used (they are user variables) so you should not have to mention them.  Also `INCLUDES` is an obsolete variable (you should use `*_CPPFLAGS` instead), and automake will warn about it if you run it with the `-Wall` option.

Comment: but AM_CPPFLAGS is not compatible if you use AM_PROG_CC_C_O. Or is it deprecated?

Comment: Why do you mean with not compatible?  I use subdir-objects and AM_CPPFLAGS in all my projects.